# Partial squash-merge

Tags: git, merge, squash

I'd like to merge my `feature`-branch into my `develop`-branch, but squash some commits into 1, while pulling in others as-is.
Is there a possibilty to `git merge --squash feature` and then to choose which commits from the `feature`-branch should be squashed and which taken as-is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nah. You must use interactive rebase in order to do pick, delete, squash etc.

```
git rebase -i HEAD~4
```

Will let you decide on the four last commits.

Comment: This has to be done on the feature-branch? So this would rewrite history of the feature-branch to just contain the commits i desire. Subsequently i could rebase my develop branch on the feature branch to pull in these commits - correct?

Comment: Yup you would do this on the feature-branch. But I probably would rebase my feature branch on the develop branch, assuming the feature branch is branched off from the develop branch that is.